# how should I do the scheduling

Tags: quartz.net

I have never written a windows service or any scheduler before so I couldn't figure out what to do.

I need to write a windows service. There is a Report table in my DB, and I need to check it every day to see if there are new reports added. Reports have receivers and the time settings, such as 15th of every month at 14:00, or daily at 12:35 or weekly on Wednesdays at 13:00. And I need to send emails with some reports at these times.

As I have decided, I will use Quartz.NET. But there are a couple of things I don't understand. So I will have 2 Jobs I think. One for checking the DB every day, to see if there are new reports that users want. And when I receive them, I'll create new different amount of Jobs with new triggers based on the times in the DB? Do I create new triggers in the job of the first daily check? I didn't understand it.

And when for example a time of one report is updated, or deleted, Do I need to delete the Job and the trigger from the scheduler? I'd appreciate the help. I am using VS 2015 with C#.

And when I do the windows service, I'll just initiate this Quartz thing that I have written? Sorry I couldn't understand what I have read so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Hangfire IO over Quartz.net
http://hangfire.io/

Its a more modern approach to scheduled jobs.  In the past I've used Quartz.net as well.  First of all, using hangfire requires no service.  The jobs are persistent, and retries are built in.  The syntax is also easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've used hangfire and its wonderful and simple.

however, Hangfire does not support Oracle db so far.  Also Quartz provide more flexibility in terms of scheduling (calendars, end dates etc).